# SQL Group By comparison with Python Group By error

Tags: python, sql

I have written the following sql query:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM CSVDatabase.dbo.sales_info
  GROUP BY Company HAVING AVG(Sales)
```

Its based on the following dataset

[image: dataset]

However, I get the following error:

> 1 An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'SET'.

I'm trying to get the mean across the whole dataset.

I have also written a python script that sets out to accomplish the same results as that in the sql script above, as follows:

```
df.groupBy('Company').mean().show()
```

The python script returns the results I would like to see from sql as shown below:

[image: dataset2]

Can someone let me know where I'm going wrong with the sql script?

Comment: `HAVING` keyword in SQL is not used to `SELECT` values

Comment: I'm sorry but what you mean here: `HAVING AVG(Sales)`. Looks like you missing condition like `HAVING AVG(Sales)>value`

Comment: When I write the same command but without HAVING AVG(Sales), ie SELECT
  *
FROM CSVDatabase.dbo.sales_info
  GROUP BY Company I get the error message: 1 Column 'CSVDatabase.dbo.sales_info.Person' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think SQL should be like below

```
SELECT Company, AVG(Sales)
FROM CSVDatabase.dbo.sales_info
GROUP BY Company
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems to me like you are trying to use `HAVING` in a wrong way. The `HAVING` clause is used for:

> HAVING filters records that work on summarized GROUP BY results.
>   HAVING applies to summarized group records, whereas WHERE applies to
>   individual records. Only the groups that meet the HAVING criteria will
>   be returned. HAVING requires that a GROUP BY clause is present. WHERE
>   and HAVING can be in the same query.

you have to move your `AVG(Sales)` in the `SELECT` clause or if you want to compere it you need to build statement in your `HAVING` clause. `HAVING AVG(Sales)>yourValue` comment down if you have more questions tnx :)